# unittest for command line arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, optionparser

How do I unit test my script for incorrect command line arguments?

For example,

> my_script.py -t

should give an error since -t flag is not present, as shown in the code below:

```
parser = OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-d",
              action="callback",
              callback=get_bios_difference,
              help="Check difference between two files"
              )

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

if len(sys.argv) == 1:  # if only 1 argument, it's the script name
   parser.print_help()
   exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a unit *to* test:

```
def parse_options(args=None):
    # Duplicating the default behavior of OptionParser.parse_args
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv[1:]

    parser = OptionParser()

    parser.add_option("-d",
                  action="callback",
                  callback=get_bios_difference,
                  help="Check difference between two files"
                  )

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args(args)

    if not args:
       parser.print_help()
       exit()
```

Note that we explicitly pass `args` to `parse_args`, rather than let it assume `sys.argv` is to be parsed.

In production, you can call `parse_options()` and it will work as before. For testing, you can call `parse_options([])` or `parse_options(["-t"])` or whatever other combination of arguments you want to test.

---

All that said, you should be using `argparse` instead of `optparse` (which has been deprecated for years) in new code.

Comment: I wrote the code. But what am I asserting?
When I run my_script.py -t . (which is an invalid argument) the terminal gives me an error

my_script.py: error: no such option: -t

Comment: You want to assert that it raises `SystemExit`; the parser just calls `optparse.error`, which ultimately just calls `sys.exit`.

Answer (score 0):

OptionParser

> Deprecated since version 2.7: The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the argparse module.

your questions has nothing to do with `unittest`? there is no need to `assert`, the `nargs=2` defined 2 items needed for `--d`.

`argparse` will check the number of args for you, here is `parameter.py`

```
import argparse
from pprint import pprint

def get_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='example of argparse')

    parser.add_argument('--d', type=str, nargs=2, help='2 files')
    return parser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    pprint(args)
```

run with 2 files:

```
parameter.py --d a b
Namespace(d=['a', 'b'])
```

When run with 1 parameter

```
parameter.py --d a
parameter.py: error: argument --d: expected 2 argument(s)
```

Comment: Any ideas how to do this in python 3?